# Create an instance of an entity within same entity in Google App Engine python ndb

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How do i create instances of an entity within the same entity. What i want is :

```
class User(ndb.model):
    friends = ndb.StructuredProperty( User, repeated=True )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update model dynamically after it was created:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  pass

User.friends = ndb.StructuredProperty(User, repeated=True)
User._fix_up_properties()
```

`_fix_up_properties` description from the sources:

```
def _fix_up_properties(cls):
    """Fix up the properties by calling their _fix_up() method.
    Note: This is called by MetaModel, but may also be called manually
    after dynamically updating a model class.
    """
```